How to filter CloudWatch metrics data by sender email or campaign in AWS SES?
I’m running email campaigns using AWS SES, where I send bulk emails, and I need to track and filter metrics (e.g., delivery, bounce, complaints) by each campaign.
Each campaign is essentially a bulk email send with my email. Now I want to filter cloudwatch metrics by those campaigns but I can't find any way to do that. I’ve already tagged my emails using the MessageTag parameter in SES, for example:
{
  "Name": "CampaignId",
  "Value": "123"
}

But I can't use the MessageTag/CampaignId dimension to filter data in CloudWatch Metrics. It returns no metrics.
My first goal is filtering the cloudwatch metrics data by anyway that belong to a specific campaign.
How can I effectively filter SES metrics (or logs) for a specific campaign?
Any guidance or detailed steps to achieve this filtering would be appreciated.

Nevermind, I did it. I added a CloudWatch dimension with Message tag is the source in the configuration set of SES to track metrics using the tag. It's working now!
